# Android: reusing listfragment in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have a `ViewPager` that essentially displays a custom view `ListFragment` except with different data. So I am thinking there must be a way I can use this same `ListFragment` but populate it with different data based on which page it shows.

Using the Google Play Store data as an example, I would like to have

1. page 1 - sort Paid Apps by Price ascending
2. page 2 - sort Paid Apps by Price descending
3. page 3 - sort Free Apps by Rating descending

How can i achieve the above? Page 1 and page 2 have the same data so it just needs to be sorted (i did it with `Collections.sort`), but page 3 shows the `ListFragment` with the same custom view except it needs to send a request to the server to download Free Apps information instead.

thank you! :)

Comment: Pass arguments to `ListFragment` using `setArguments()` method and use this information in your pages to differentiate and adopt different behavior.

Comment: hmmm is that done in the `getItem` method of my `FragmentPagerAdapter` ?

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/lalit3686/ViewPagerDemo) example to see how you can pass arguments to Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well, here's the setup I assume you have.

Each `ListView` is supplied data via a `ListAdapter` of some sort.

A `ViewPager` is supplied by a `PagerAdapter`.

In this case, you can use a single `ListAdapter` that sorts the same exact information in whatever order you want.

Your `FragmentPagerAdapter` can supply the same adapter to each fragment that shares the data.  Each fragment can request the data in whatever order it wants, and the adapter will sort it and send the values off via the `getView()` method when the fragment builds its view.

In the case of the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it will swap out fragments and keep them in memory so they are already being reused for you.  However, their views can be destroyed and rebuilt.  Every time a `ListFragment` rebuilds its view, it will call the `getView()` method of the supplied adapter.  The `getView()` method returns each row of the list based on the position requested.

Because it's all the same data, you only need one adapter holding the data.  However, it needs the ability to get the information in the order that you request. This can be done in numerous ways, but really all the `ListFragment` cares about is what it receives from `getView()`.  Thus, your `ListFragment` can tell your Adapter the order that it wants to receive data.  Then your adapter can supply the data in that order based off the position value of `getView()`.

Comment: am i right to say that the above solution only caters to sorting of the data (in my Google Play Store example sorting Top Paid Apps in ascending and descending order)? also, to clarify my setup (because i am not sure if it matches exactly what you said), each `ListFragment` is supplied data via an `ArrayAdapter`, and my `ViewPager` is supplied by a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. My `ArrayAdapter` is created and `ListAdapter` is set in the `asyncTaskCompleted` when my service call returns. How do i have the `ViewPagerAdapter` communicate with my `ListAdapter` in this case?

Comment: Your `FragmentPagerAdapter` creates the fragments, correct?  If that's the case then it should also be the one that supplies the `ArrayAdapter` to your `ListFragment` upon creation.  `FragmentPagerAdapter` can destroy the fragment's view at any time, so when it needs to rebuild it, it will do so via whatever `Adapter` you supply it.  In this case, since it's all the same data but sorted in different ways, you can have a single `ArrayAdapter` that's used by every list.  Each list will ask the order it wants, and the adapter can supply the views in that order.

Comment: I think I explained it wrong initially.  I've updated my answer.  Hopefully it's less confusing.